Applying Slater-Koster tight binding method for Rhombohedral Bi
I am trying to build a tight-binding Hamiltonian for Bi which has the $D_{3d}$ point group and $R\bar{3}m$ space group. It has two inequivalent atoms in the unit-cell.
I understood the basics of the method from ''Applications of Group Theory
to the Physics of Solids
M. S. Dresselhaus''. But here the example is given for a simple cubic material which does not have inequivalent atoms. So, for this case, simply knowing which orbitals I want to make a tight-binding model for is enough.
How should I proceed if I want to make a model for this material, specially as there are two inequivalent Bi atoms which I have to take into consideration. Are there any examples apart from ''Dresselhaus, G., and M. S. Dresselhaus. "Fourier expansion for the electronic energy bands in silicon and germanium." Physical Review 160.3 (1967): 649.'' which would be helpful?
Any help/suggestion will be appreciated.
Regards,
Farhan
